# Delphi how to determine which procedure called the another procedure?

Tags: delphi

How can i determine who called the Showme Procedure?

```
procedure Showme(str:string);
begin
  ShowMessage(str);
end;

procedure btnclick(sender:TObject);
begin
  Showme("test");
end;

procedure btn2click(sender:TObject);
begin
  Showme("test");
end;
```

Edit : The Confusion

```
Showme(654, '654'); // procedure name, string
Showme(654, '564');
```

Comment: What are you using to generate "The Confusion". The code you've posted won't generate that output. If your two click events say Showme("654") and Showme("564") then that would make sense (but makes your question meaningless).

Comment: The Confused Procedure is my suggestion to my friend. But he won't use it.

Comment: I understand the original question better than the edited version (but that's me probably), but I don't understand the downvotes?!

Comment: I fail to understand what you mean with your edit. If `Showme` is a procedure that requires exactly one argument, of course it will not compile if you pass two arguments to it.

Comment: The first example is the original proc. The edited version is my procedure with an extra parameter.

Comment: Upvote this. Downvoting without giving a reason is a bad habit.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's no built-in way for one procedure to know which procedure called it.  You can use stack tracing if you really need to know, but that sort of data is really only needed for debugging.  For actual execution, what matters is the data that's passed to the routines, not where it came from.  That's one of the basic principles of structured programming.  If two different routines call the same procedure with the same data, it should treat them both the same.

What exactly are you doing where you need to be able to tell the difference?  There might be a simpler way to accomplish it.

Comment: my friend is an old-head programmer and he will do this without an extra parameter and I am just curious about that, is there any other way for do this.

Comment: No, as Mason told you there is only stack trace but that is not advised. You friend has a wrong approach. Tell him to just use an extra parameter. Why he refuses that? If he is afraid that parameter list will be to long, he can use a record and pass that as a single parameter.

Comment: @drorhan: Aha, an old-head programmer which doesn't use the internet, could ask this question and explain it by himself. Such kind of old-head programmer? ;-)

Comment: +1 for the proper reasoning as to why this is not a good idea.

Answer (score 8):

Why don't you pass a different constant or even the name of the procedure calling it as a parameter of Showme? It is possible to analyze the stack in order to determine the name of the calling function but it is much more complicated and you need to add information about linking (map file). Jedi's JCL has some functions that can help you but I would use an additional parameter.

Comment: my friend asked me about that and i told them what you say. but he will only send one parameter because the confusion

Comment: There really are only two answers: pass a parameter; or look at the call stack. The call stack is complex and it's not a good idea to use that to control program flow (if you call Showme() from somewhere else what happens?) You could look at the parameter you have but that's not reliable either.

Answer (score 2):

I will assume you're running the application in the debugger, so you can put a breakpoint inside the Showme procedure and when the program stops, activate the stack view (view/debug windows/Call stack).

It will show you who called it and actually if you double click on any stack entry the IDE will walk you to the exact line of code that makes the call (in case showme is called more than once per calling routine).

BTW: I think you have to make a better effort to express your question.

Answer (score 2):

[TVirtualMethodInterceptor](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/RTTI.TMethodImplementation) allows to execute code before and after the actual method, and there is a Method parameter which contain the method name:

Example code:

```
type
  TFoo = class
  public
    procedure Bar; virtual;
  end;

procedure InterceptorBefore(Instance: TObject; Method: TRttiMethod;
  const Args: TArray<TValue>; out DoInvoke: Boolean; out Result: TValue);
begin
  ShowMessage('Before: ' + Instance.ClassName + '.' + Method.Name);
end;

procedure InterceptorAfter(Instance: TObject; Method: TRttiMethod;
  const Args: TArray<TValue>; var Result: TValue);
begin
  ShowMessage('After: ' + Instance.ClassName + '.' + Method.Name);
end;

{ TFoo }

procedure TFoo.Bar;
begin
  ShowMessage('TFoo.Bar');
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  interceptor: TVirtualMethodInterceptor;
  foo: TFoo;
begin
  foo := TFoo.Create;

  interceptor := TVirtualMethodInterceptor.Create(TFoo);
  interceptor.Proxify(foo);
  interceptor.OnBefore := InterceptorBefore;
  interceptor.OnAfter := InterceptorAfter;

  foo.Bar;

end;
```

Note this is new in Delphi XE so I can not test and verify it on my system.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you are on [modern Delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8950513/what-does-at-returnaddress-mean-in-delphi):

```
procedure Showme(str:string);
var
  Caller: Pointer;
begin
  // This will save address of the NEXT CPU opcode AFTER the call into your function
  Caller := ReturnAddress;  
  // Shift the address, so it will be in the middle of the call into your function
  // It is kinda a hack: the proper code would move address back to the size of the call opcode itself - which is not a trivial thing to do
  // It is optional: you can skip it, if you are OK with the address of next opcode after the call
  Caller := PAnsiChar(Caller) - 1;

  ShowMessage(str);
end;
```

Once you have obtained the pointer to the call instruction to your function, you need to convert that address to a human-readable string. It is not possible by default, since the compiled executable does not contain function names, only RAW addresses (there are exceptions, like RTTI, but it is not a general case).

However, if you attach debug information to your executable, then you will be able to read it to convert address to name. For example,  if you have EurekaLog:

```
uses
  EDebugInfo;

procedure Showme(str:string);
var
  Caller: Pointer;
  FunctionName: String;
begin
  Caller := ReturnAddress;  
  Caller := PAnsiChar(Caller) - 1;
  FunctionName := GetLocationInfoStr(Caller);
  ShowMessage(FunctionName + ': ' + str);
end;
```

However:

1. It will only work if you are compiling with some debug information (and the [corresponding debug info provider is enabled](https://www.eurekalog.com/help/eurekalog/debug_information_page_code.php)):

- EurekaLog has its own debug info format, which can be optionally compressed (which is actually not recomended, as you will spend more memory and CPU).
- It also supports JCL/JEDI, Synopse/MAB, as well as .map, .tds/TD32, .dbg, .pdb.

2. It is **NOT** a constant. The name will be looked up dynamically, so it have some run-time costs.

P.S. Please note, that you should only do that only for logging/debugging purposes. Your app logic should not be implemented like this. You should use classes, virtual functions, RTTI, dispatch tables, or scripting engine - depending of what you are trying to do.