# What does `at ReturnAddress` mean in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, exception

While browsing System.Zip (Delphi XE2) to see how it works, I found this function:

```
procedure VerifyWrite(Stream: TStream; var Buffer; Count: Integer);
begin
  if Stream.Write(Buffer, Count) <> Count then
    raise EZipException.CreateRes(@SZipErrorWrite) at ReturnAddress;
end;
```

It's the `at ReturnAddress` part that sort of puzzles me.

I didn't know that `at` was a valid keyword (the syntax highlighter doesn't seem to recognise it either).

According to the IDE it's declared as `System.ReturnAddress`, but I can only find it declared as a label somewhere in the (asm) code of `procedure _HandleAnyException;`.  The system unit is full of references to it though.

So what I would like to know is this:

1. **What is `ReturnAddress`?**
2. **What exactly does `Raise Exception.Create ... at ReturnAddress` do?**

Bonuspoints if you can give a real-world example of where this would be a useful construct, or if you can advice against using it.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`ReturnAddress` is the address to which `VerifyWrite` would have returned when finished.

`Raise Exception.Create... at ReturnAddress` means that when the exception dialog is displayed, it would indicate the address of the exception as being at `ReturnAddress`. In other words, the exception message would read `Exception <whatever> raised at <ReturnAddress>: <Exception Message>`.

Here is an excerpt from the help file for Delphi 7. It's nearly the same as [the online version](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Exceptions#Raising_and_Handling_Exceptions).

> To raise an exception object, use an instance of the exception 
>   class with a raise statement. For example,
>
> ```
> raise EMathError.Create;
> ```
>
> In general, the form of a raise statement is
>
> ```
> raise object at address
> ```
>
> where object and at address are both optional; see 
>   Re-raising exceptions. When an address is specified, 
>   it can be any expression that evaluates to a pointer 
>   type, but is usually a pointer to a procedure or function. 
>   For example:
>
> ```
> raise Exception.Create('Missing parameter') at @MyFunction;
> ```
>
> Use this option to raise the exception from an earlier point 
>   in the stack than the one where the error actually occurred.

Note the last sentence in particular. It's pretty specific about the use of `at <address>`.

Comment: @ain: Thanks for the formatting assist. Didn't mean to remove the fact you edited - just wanted to stress the final sentence of the quoted text. :)

Comment: And the real-world use for this construct is generally if you use a *helper function* for raising an exception. In the VCL, for example, there's `TList.Error`, where all the `TList`-related errors come from. Knowing an exception was raised in that function isn't useful for debugging, so it uses the `at` syntax to put the exception address back in the function that called `Error`, so when you look up the address in your map file, you have a better idea who the culprit was. (And why use a helper? For one, it keeps the codegen of the callers simpler.)

Comment: @RobKennedy: Wouldn't the call stack reveal the same info?

Comment: If you *have* the call stack, @Afrazier, then sure. But the `at` syntax has existed since 1995. Back then, MadExcept wasn't around to give you a nice crash report from a customer.

Answer (score 10):

`ReturnAddr` was not a puzzle with previous Delphi versions. Consider next test (Delphi XE):

```
procedure RaiseTest1;

  procedure RaiseException(ReturnAddr: Pointer);
  begin
    raise Exception.Create('OOPS!') at ReturnAddr;
  end;

asm
      POP    EAX
      JMP    RaiseException
end;

procedure RaiseTest2;
begin
  raise Exception.Create('OOPS!');
end;


procedure TForm1.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  RaiseTest1;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button4Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  RaiseTest2;
end;
```

if you press Button3 under debugger and press 'Break' in exception messagebox, debugger stops at

```
procedure TForm1.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  RaiseTest1; // <-- here
end;
```

if you press Button4, debugger stops at

```
procedure RaiseTest2;
begin
  raise Exception.Create('OOPS!');  // <-- here
end;
```

As you can see RaiseTest1 modifies default exception stack frame and makes debugging a bit more straightforward since the only purpose of RaiseTest1(2) procedures is to raise an exception.

I guess something changed in XE2 so that `ReturnAddr` syntax is simplified.

Comment: I don't understand what syntax you think changed.

Comment: @RobKennedy I think he means from `ReturnAddr` to `ReturnAddress`, but I could not find any documentation for this. But it seems that `ReturnAddr` was the name of nested functions in system units (see this [bug](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=71294)).