# Creating or forcing an error in Delphi

Tags: delphi

For some of my procedures and functions, I have implemented various checks on parameters in order to force execution to stop if parameters are out of range in one way or another.
I find it better to check for this in my own code rather than have an abnormal crash due to a perhaps bad memory-write.

Consider the simple code:

```
PROCEDURE Test(OneDigitNumbers:BYTE);
BEGIN
  IF OneDigitNumbers>9 THEN ProduceErrorMessage;
END;

begin
  Test( 1);
  Test( 2);
  Test( 9);
  Test(12);
end.
```

I have no problem in actually producing an error message, my only "problem" is that the debugger in Delphi always point to the procedure creating the exception.
Is there a method of creating this exception or error message so that the debugger point to the line where the parameter is out of range?
In my example, it should point to :

```
Test(12);
```

and maybe say something like "Parameter out of range. Valid range is 0-9. Parameter passed was: 12"

Even an answer to say that this is NOT possible will be useful (if you know for sure that this is not possible), because then I will just forget about this and make an alternative method for debugging.

Comment: when an exception is raised under the debugger, you can look at callstack, based on your example, the callstack would have the first item ProduceErrorMessage(meaning this is where the exception is raised), the second item is Test(the procedure that called the ProduceErrorMessage procedure) and the third item would be the function/procedure/method where Test was called.

Comment: @ComputerSaysNo - thank you for this tip :) I was not aware of this.
Maybe it is possible to play with the callstack before raising the exception ? Just to make it go 2 or 3 steps backwards ?

Comment: Don't mess with the callstack. It will get you in more trouble than you are in now. Inspect it perhaps. And use what you find there in your Exception message. The Exception class does offer access to the callstack in newer versions, but it requires the exception having been created, perhaps even raised. In the latter case you would have to raise the exception and catch it in your function so that you can modify the message and then re-raise it to propagate to the calling code. Bit messy but it could be done.

Comment: I am just about to post an elaboration.

Comment: A more theoretical issue.. You're testing for preconditions here, and that test should take place **outside** of your routine, and not inside. It's counter intuitive, but that's how you write clean code. If the caller asks something that doesn't make sense, you can't expect the callee to deal with he situation. For safety you might add asserts inside the routine, but you may never rely on those outside of the routine. Otherwise, you can losen up the preconditions to officially accept other types of input.

Comment: @WoutervanNifterick: Huh? I'm confused by your assertions (sorry). Asserts are all nice and good, but often more specific exception types are very helpful and that would mean not using `assert`s but simple `if`s and `raise Exxx.Create`s. What then is the difference between testing preconditions and asserts? And why would one but not the other be allowed inside for "safety"? To me they are all pre and post contract validations and I would want them inside the functions. Any test harnass should check that the assertions and/or specific exception types are actually generated on invalid input.

Comment: @WoutervanNifterick You've got that backwards. You can't expect the callee to *deal* with the problem, but you must expect the callee to *detect* the problem.

Comment: The callee will detect that certain parameters is outside the allowed range. This is no problem. The problem is only to make the errorhandler in the callee to point the error to where it originates from. Not only the procedure, but the actual code-line which gave the faulty parameters to the procedure.
Anyway. I have a few approaches to test out now :)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: no, they've taught me that principle years ago in university, and i've been in debates about it often. You may add asserts in a routine to prevent sending wrong emails or wiping a disk, but checking a precondition inside a routine is definitely the wrong place. It always needs to be done outside, no matter what. Pascal doesn't promote doing this in a structured way. People abuse exceptions and asserts instead of structuring their code properly. Or, even worse, they just don't have clear preconditions. It's a hell for structured testing.

Comment: @WoutervanNifterick Pascal doesn't promote that or indeed promote the other. I guess we must be talking at cross purposes though. You cannot really believe that callers must perform parameter validation. Plenty of times the callee cannot since it does not have the information with which to check. Consider an `Add` function for a dictionary. You really expect the caller to check whether or not the key is already contained in the dictionary?

Comment: @WoutervanNifterick : I suppose... this "problem" of mine is not really about dealing with a real exception. It is about catching something the code may allow for but would lead to wrong results, then   force an exception with a detailed error-message in order to quickly be able to debug the cause of it. In my case, it is never the actual routine where the fault is. It is always the parameters passed to the routine. Depending on parameters, the checking will be different. It is basically a very verstile snippet of code that is highly reuseable due to params. It always catch what it should

Comment: not allow for, but for ease of debugging the cause, I would just trick the debugger to point to the line of origin. I can't see that this is a wrong approach if it is possible to do so. The point of object oriented programming (or any programming) must be to make versatile, universal, and ultimately highly reusable code where possible. At least I find that much better than copy'n'paste spaghetticode that grows out of proportions and after a while is impossible to grasp pecause of its mere size. On a few projects I have done, I have been able to shrink 20.000 lines into 5.000 lines.

Comment: Ultimately, another point of having this "exception handler" inside the callee is: When software is fully tested and no more "exceptions" occur, there is no further need for it. It can be taken out with a single "//" and hence my software will gain speed.
If having this errorchecking everywhere, it will just be a big job to first add, and then remove the checking when everything is flawless.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: yes, it's the responsibility of the caller to ask a valid question. In your example or the dictionary: if the precondition says that it's allowed to supply an existing keyword, then there is nothing wrong. If the precondition states that the supplied keyword must be unique, then it's plain wrong to perform the check inside of the routine. Inside of the routine you must be able to rely on the fact that the preconditions are met. Neither detection nor handling of situations where they are not met should be part of the routine itself. It's often counter intuitive though.

Comment: @Wouter I just cannot understand what you are talking about. I agree that the callee should not check that the interface contract is obeyed. For example, it's not the callee's job to check that a paramter of type TMyClass really does contain one of them. But we aren't talking about that. We are talking about a function that is designed to carry out a test. Its job is to raise an exception if the test fails. The pre-condition is that it is sent an integer. It's not checking that.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: it's clear that the OP intends on having a routine with the precondition that OneDigitnumbers is 0..9. The check if it reallly is in that range should not be inside of the routine. Now the precondition is that you can throw any byte at the routine, but sometimes it will throw an error. So you still need to check for errors outside of the routine, and you still need to deal with it. The software just became a bit harder to test because of this. That's my point. Maybe it's a coding style thing.

Comment: @Wouter Sorry. I've no idea what your point is. I can't imagine why you would replace one line of code in a shared routine with 100 (hopefully) identical lines at every location which calls that routine. I can't imagine that making sense. I must be misunderstanding you.

Comment: @WoutervanNifterick: I hope you don't think my simple code in the question is my level of coding, and that is the complexity of it all.
I just wrote the tiniest possible code in order to convey my question.
The actual routine is using and working with a Dynamic resizeable threedimensional array where individual parts can be resized.

Comment: @WoutervanNifterick: I think I understand your point about having to check for the error in the routine or procedure calling the callee. That is however not the issue here. My software is not supposed to handle any errors that may arize from the callee. The whole point is only to catch the error at the line of origin when testing and debugging the software.

Comment: @MortenBrendefur: i just made a remark.. It's some built in alarm that goes off when i see preconditions being checked inside a routine rather than outside. I understand that this was just an example to demonstrate something unrelated to that.

Comment: It is always good with remarks :)
Some times one find something very useful that one has not thought of.
As for preconditions to be checked inside or outside of a routine..
I would just say that IF this precondition is Always to be tested for, then it makes more sense to put it inside the routine in order to minimize codewriting.
Kind of "Keep relatives together". And high-school or university teaching is good for the basics. It is when able to think outside the box when solving problems that you really excels at it. :)
Unfortunately, schools are more about the box than whats outside.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To answer the question as asked, you can make the test function inline:

```
procedure Test(OneDigitNumbers: byte); inline;
```

The compiler will then write the code for Test into each calling function. Whilst you can do this, my advice is that you do not. It's just a trick but I don't think it really helps you.

If you want to raise the exception at the return address, you can do this:

```
raise Exception.CreateFmt(
  'Exception blah blah at %p.',
  [ReturnAddress]
) at ReturnAddress;
```

If you want to go further up the stack, then you'll have to use something like [`CaptureStackBackTrace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/bb204633.aspx). Combine the back trace with raise at and you can raise the exception at any point in the call stack, if really you think that's a good idea. I do not think it's a good idea, as I explain below.

If you use a good debugging tool, like madExcept, then the call stacks in the madExcept bug reports will tell you all you need to know when an error occurs.

---

With the extra clarification in the comments, it seems that what you really want to happen is for the exception to contain information from higher up the call stack. To my mind it is a violation of encapsulation to ask the callee to report information about its caller. So if you want to include information from the caller, let the caller catch the exception, add the information, and re-raise.

Comment: Amazing :)
This answered one of my other never thought about questions about Inline. Absolutely most useful.

I can however not use this inline approach for my out of range checking. I fear that my program would grow beyond proportions.
Maybe it is possible to read the stacktrace before calling the exception.?
I always know that the originating call is 2 steps backwards. Maybe it is possible to force stacktrace to go 2 steps backwards before raising the exception ?

Comment: For fear of your program growing beyond proportions? Why be scared. Scared of what? What's going to happen? If you want range checking, enable range checking? Do you know how to do that.

Comment: :) It is not that I am afraid of a program of 100 mb. It does not matter much on todays computers.
I just prefer to keep my program nice and small.
And when I test my software, I always run with rangechecking activated.
For speed later, when everything works, I deactivate it.
But it is not only about range-checking. It is the ability to produce designed error-messages, pointing to the specific codeline where it originates from when raising the exception. Range-checking still would only tell where the actual problem lies, not the cause of the problem.

Comment: Put madExcept in your program. Let it do its magic for you. It has all that you need.

Comment: My point is to have my very own range-checking in order to produce designed error-messages that pinpoint whats wrong. To enable range checking in the compiler does nothing of the sort :)
This answer is very close to what I am after. Maybe if I use Inline on my procedure for creating the designed error message, and then point the exception to the [ReturnAddress]) at ReturnAddress;
Thank you very much for this information :)
Also thank you for tip about madExcept :)

Comment: Newer Delphi versions (certainly from XE2) provide access to the stacktrace through the `Exception` class. No need for Windows API stuff by yourself.

Comment: @Marjan No they don't. You still need to do the stack tracing yourself. There is a field in the Exception class. But the RTL won't populate it. You need to do so.

Comment: @MortenBrendefur The normal way to do what you describe is for the caller to catch the exception, add some details, and re-raise.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Confused. I can't recall doing anything special and I am getting stacktraces from that field in my debug logging. However, we do use madexcept so maybe it has got its hooks in there and adds the stack trace. Will check when I get to a machine with that code on it.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I realize the normal way of catching the exception is from the caller. My problem as such is that I really would like to avoid that because that would mean to add exception-handling in almost every single routine I write. All button-handlers and others where my routines are used. It must somehow be better to handle the exception (One time) from the routine called, rather than write 500 exception handlers in all buttons or procedures/functions calling the routines. :) Maybe not Normal, but if it works, much more efficient, and only messy code one place (if messy it is gonna be)

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for a [subrange type](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/Simple_Types#Subrange_Types).

```
type
  TOneDigitNumber = 0..9;

procedure Test(OneDigitNumbers: TOneDigitNumber);
begin
  // Do something
end;

begin
  Test( 1);
  Test( 2);
  Test( 9);
  Test(12);   // compiler error '[DCC Error] MyStuffTest.pas(33): E1012 Constant expression violates subrange bounds
end.
```

Comment: The rangesetting is a very good trick, it is however not possible to use because the range will be different for maybe each single call to the procedure. Everything (almost) I make is based on a dynamic structure with dynamic arrays that grows or shrinks depending on a need for space basis.
The rangechecking in Delphi would not work if setting X:=35; and then do Test(X); or even as a loop: For X:=0 to 35 DO Test(X);

Comment: Dynamic arrays cannot be checked for ranges, because they're *dynamic*. The compiler can't check the range for out of bounds values, because they're dynamic (they can be changed at runtime). Your question mentions nothing about arrays or any such information; your `Test` procedure accepts a single `Byte` value. If you have a different question now, please post it as such. If your entire question is different, you should delete this one and post that one instead. You can't change the definition of the problem after the fact. :-)

Comment: Yes you can do this for literals, but that's not terribly useful

Comment: @KenWhite : The whole point is not Dynamic Arrays or Compiler to check for errors. The point is to create an exception in such a way that the Delphi Debugger display the codeline of origin. The codeline where the error originates from. It is not the compilers job to find the error, because it can never do on my procedures. I can catch errors as in out of range parameters myself. I just can not point the debugger directly to the line of origin when I create the exception. I wish to make a procedure like "RaiseExceptionAt_ProcedureCaller"

Answer (score 1):

A bit of an elaboration on my comment to your question

```
type
  EMyOwnRangeError = class(ERangeError)
    // You can also add your own member variables for easier inspection
  public
    constructor CreateFrom(const aRangeError: ERangeError);
  end;

constructor EMyOwnRangeError.CreateFrom(const aRangeError: ERangeError);
begin
  // Do whatever you need to inspect the call stack in aRangeError 
  // and modify the message and/or set any extra member variable that you
  // you define on EMyOwnRangeError.
  // No help from me on this, quite simply because I don't have Delphi 
  // installed on the machine I am currently working at.
end;

procedure MySpecialTest(const aWhatever: Byte);
begin
  try
    if (aWhatever < 0) or (aWhatever > SOMEUPPERRANGE) then
      raise ERangeError.Create;

    // Normal code for MySpecialTest

  except
    on E: ERangeError do raise EMyOwnRangeError.CreateFrom(E);
    else
      raise; // Make sure other exceptions are propagated.
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have now tested basically the approach in the idea I got from David Heffernan.
I simply added this simple code in one of my units of reuseables:

```
PROCEDURE TestError(Par:BYTE);
  BEGIN
    TRY
    FINALLY
      IF Par>9 THEN Raise Exception.CreateFmt('Error Blah blah blah at ',[Par]) AT @Par;
    END;
  END;
```

When this procedure is called with a parameter higher than 9 then it forces an exception.
Delphi ask "Break or Continue" and I click Break.

The result is almost what I would like, but it is so close that I can live with that.
The debugger pops up with a nice red line on the line AFTER the one calling the procedure.

I tried withouth the TRY-Finally-End also, and then it is plain wrong, actually showing the red line another level back from the callstack..

Anyway. I feel that this result is an awful lot better than what I had before. Now my debugging will be a joy rather than a pain.
Thank you :)

Comment: Why would you raise at @par? That's a local variable in you function.

Comment: I did not get your "at %p.', [ReturnAddress]) at ReturnAddress;" to work.  %p is not recognized, and ReturnAddress is not recognized.
So I just tested around a little. It was kind of logical, because that Par is the only link to the caller that is visible to me. I don't know how to find the return address.

Comment: Are you using a legacy delphi? You find the return address on the stack. It gets pushed there by the call instruction.

Comment: I am using CodeGear Delphi 2009. As for the "To find the return address on the stack", I don't know how to do this :-(

Comment: Yes, `ReturnAddress` has changed since then. Here's a question that might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8950513/what-does-at-returnaddress-mean-in-delphi  Also take a look at the implementation of `SysUtils.Abort` in D2009. That shows you how to pop the return address off the stack. If you want a deeper backtrace, use `CaptureStackBackTrace`.